# Monolog 2.9.1 - Logging as json object instead of string

Tags: php, json, monolog

I have recently upgraded monolog version to 2.9.1 from ^1.23".
Earlier, when I used $logger->debug(...), it used to log my responses in splunk as a json readable object.

After upgrade, it logs debug messages as a single string

```
log : {....}
```

The entire payload with all keys values pairs is logged as string and is truncated after a limit.

I have tried setting handler with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, but it still gives the same result. Is there any other setting I am missing here ?

Note : If there is any error, the errors are still logged in JSON format